# How to show views calendar by node field_date

Tags: views, datetime

I have a date field with **start,end** dates.

But i can't understood how to show it in a views block by contextial filter **date** -> **content from node**

[image]
[image]

Thanks for any help!)

Comment: actually, you're doing right. what are you showing in the view and where do you display the block ?

Comment: i just enter the id of the node in field "Preview with contextual filters"

Answer (score 2):

Just configured your Contextual filters like below snapshot.

[image: Snapshot 1]

[image: Snapshot 2]

Comment: hmm doesn't work(